# C accessing array correctly

Tags: c

os-sim.h

```
typedef enum {
    PROCESS_NEW = 0,
    PROCESS_READY,
    PROCESS_RUNNING,
    PROCESS_WAITING,
    PROCESS_TERMINATED
} process_state_t;

typedef struct _pcb_t {
    const unsigned int pid;
    const char *name;
    const unsigned int static_priority;
    process_state_t state;               <<---Trying to access this
    op_t *pc;
    struct _pcb_t *next;
} pcb_t;
```

file1.c

```
static pcb_t **current;

extern void yield(unsigned int cpu_id)
{
    /* FIX ME */
    while (1)
    {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&current_mutex);
    current[cpu_id].state = PROCESS_WAITING;  ///<-------ERROR HERE
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&current_mutex);
    break;
    }
    schedule(cpu_id);
}

in main method():  
current = malloc(sizeof(pcb_t*) * 10);
```

I have error in this line `current[cpu_id].state = PROCESS_WAITING;`

```
error: request for member ‘state’ in something not a structure or union
```

What does this error mean?
Is this not the right way to access current array which holds pcb_t?
If so, how do i access the current array? and state field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're likely looking for:

```
current[cpu_id]->state = PROCESS_WAITING;
```

The type of `current` is `pcb_t **`. So the type of `current[cpu_id]` is `pcb_t *`.

Comment: so you use -> when it's ** and you use . when it's *?

Comment: @sharth Wait, if he allocated memory for only 10 pointers `malloc(sizeof(pcb_t*) * 10)` then how does that work? He can't store anything in `state` as space hasn't been allocated(?)

Comment: @Armin: That's a good point. I'd be happy to see you expand on that point in either a separate answer, as an edit to mine, or in these comments.